# Phone gap HTML5 unable to open the camera

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins

In the config.xml file I've added

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture"/>`

In the index.html file

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
...
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>`

Then in the Javascript tag

```
    <script>
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

     // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

     // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

      // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
      alert(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    function capturePhoto() {
        alert("I am here");
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
        });
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
</script>
```

On the button click I am getting the alert 'I am here' which mean the html button is calling the capturePhoto() function.
And I am not getting any error alert!

But the camera is not opening!

I am using the online https://build.phonegap.com/ in order to get the apk

I've been stuck on this for a while.. any advice please ?

Comment: Are you able to connect your device to a chrome debugger? It looks like there was a JS error in navigator.camera.getPicture, maybe missing? Also, have a look at the documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#module_camera.getPicture  they say, the object is not available until the deviceready ready event, make sure you're calling it after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding an older version of 'cordova-plugin-camera' using spec="2.0"

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.0" />`

and also added

`<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>`

Does anyone know what's the latest 'cordova-plugin-camera' version that is compatible with cli-6.5.0 ?